# How to use ReadFileEx in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone suggest how to use ReadFileEx in C# , Currently i m using ReadFile:

```
string targetdeviceId = @"\\.\D:";
targetdiskHandle = CreateFile(targetdeviceId, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

int rvalRead = ReadFile(targetdiskHandle, smallByteArray, smallByteArray.Length, out numBytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);
```

The issue I am facing is that in large read operations this call hangs and even the process is not getting killed in task manager, Even more Windows is not getting rebooted and I have to do a hard reboot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how large does the `large file` maybe have?

Comment: It is a 300GB volume., I am reading in loop of 3MB each time.

Comment: Why on earth would you use PInvoke for file access?  Use System.IO or memory mapped files.

Comment: you can using a variable `istop` to control loop to stop, when `istop` is true, then break this loop.

Comment: Looks like difference between ReadFile and ReadFileEx is the callback method.  To see example of callback see pinvoke : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumThreadWindows.html

Comment: You are poking the file system driver directly with this code.  And more worrisome, the anti-malware product installed on the machine.  Start there first, disable it and try again.  And do consider using FileStream.Begin/Read() instead, use the constructor that takes IntPtr to pass the handle.

Comment: Can you explain in more details, I am trying to read an entire ntfs volume and not a file